# How to understand "how glad I am I came here instead"?

Tags: sentence-structure

> My name was down for Eton, you know, I can't tell you **how glad I am I came here instead**.

I can probably get its meaning, but I'm not sure about its structure. I can easily understand: I can't tell you **how gladly I came here instead**. Why do we need to add "**I am**" in the middle? It doesn't look so grammatical to me. What kind of structure is it?

~ From Harry Potter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help to add a "that" in the middle of the sentence:

> I can't tell you how glad I am **that** I came here instead.

In this way you can see "I came here instead" is a subordinate clause of "how glad I am".  Or think of it as two thoughts conjoined: "how glad I am" (a rhetorical phrase essentially meaning "I am *very* glad") and "I am glad I came here instead".  The author could have just said:

> I am very glad I came here instead.

But this is straightforward and dull.  The "I can't tell you how X I am" adds character and nuance to the passage.

As you probably already know, it's common to omit these kind of relative pronouns when they are not absolutely necessary.  Similar examples:

> How lucky we are **(that)** you came along when you did.
>
> The cave is so deep **(that)** you can't see the bottom.

Comment: Any effect that "when you did" has added to the whole sentence "How lucky we are (that) you came along when you did"?

Comment: @dan  Not really.  It's mostly just adds a time frame to the expression, and suggests the speaker had some kind of *urgent* need.  There are many expressions that could fit, "at that moment", "in the nick of time", "just when we were about to sink into the quicksand", etc.

Comment: Isn't that a conjunction, not a pronoun in this context?

Comment: @Kreiri  It's possible it is, but all that detailed grammar nomenclature stuff feels like "splitting hairs" to me.  I found a reference that calls it a relative pronoun, but I'm happy to change it to "conjunction" if you can find a better reference to support that.

Comment: It isn't a pronoun. It can go in the same slot sometimes (_the man that/whom I was talking to_) but it can't do all the things a pronoun can (_the main about whom I was talking_, but not _about that I was talking_). Modern treatments usually refer to it as a _subordinator_.

Answer (score 1):

Compare:

> {I can't tell you} { {how glad I am} (that) {I came here instead} }.
>
> {I can't tell you} { {how doubtful we are} (that) {the legislation will pass} }.
>
> {I can't tell you} { {how surprised she was} (that) {she won the lottery} }.

The finite clause ending the sentences complements the middle expression, the *how*-clause.

That middle expression with its complement in turn complements the main clause, *I can't tell you*.

The meaning of this statement that "I can't tell you" is akin to "Words cannot express".

In other words:

I am *very* glad, glad beyond my ability to express my gladness.

We are *very* doubtful, doubtful beyond my ability to express our doubt.

She was *very* surprised, surprised beyond my ability to express her surprise.

The *how*-clause includes "I am" and "we are" and "she was" because "glad" and "doubtful" and "surprised" are not characteristic of the coming here or the legislation passing or winning the lottery; rather they are attitudes of the *subject* of the *how*-clause in relation to those events. **Glad** and **doubtful** and **surprised** are *states of mind* of "I" and "we" and "she", respectively.